# PowerShell: Select custom expression and expand in one operation

Tags: powershell, select-object

I can do something like

```
ls . `
| select @{ Name="Dir"; Expression = { $_ | Split-Path } } `
| select -ExpandProperty Dir
```

to select a custom expression (in this case `$_ | Split-Path`) into a simple array of values.

Is there a way to merge the two select statements into one, that still yields equivalent results?

Comment: `(ls | select @{ Name="Dir"; Expression = { $_ | Split-Path } }).dir` ?

Comment: @arco444: That's better, but it still requires me to choose a name and construct the entire object. Is there no way to just give the expression `{ $_ | Split-Path }` and a flag or something that indicates I want the values as a plain array?

Comment: `it still requires me to choose a name and construct the entire object` you should only do this if you actually need an object. If you're just looking to transform a single property and capture the output, use a `foreach`

Comment: i.e. from your question: `ls | % { $_ | Split-Path }`. This method would work given the comment you left on the answer. Perhaps you should add this information in the question.

Comment: Do you mean `Get-ChildItem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DirectoryName`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to do? You could get the same results with just `ls`/`Get-ChildItem` and `Split-Path`. Not sure if you need the `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::` part.

```
PS C:\Path\To\Dir> Get-ChildItem | Split-Path
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Path\To\Dir
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Path\To\Dir
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Path\To\Dir

PS C:\Path\To\Dir> (Get-ChildItem).FullName | Split-Path
C:\Path\To\Dir
C:\Path\To\Dir
C:\Path\To\Dir
```

**Edit**

Assuming `nuget list <my-package>` outputs a string array, you can use `-replace` and regex (`$` to match string end) to manipulate it and get an array of results.

```
$((nuget list <my-package>).Replace(" ",",") -replace "$",".nupkg")
```

Comment: In reality, I do this against the result of `nuget list <my-package>`, and the expression is actually `{ "$($_.Replace(" ", ",")).nupkg" }` but I wanted an example that could run on any computer, not just mine, so your approach isn't really applicable.

Comment: @TomasLycken OK, that's thoroughly confusing. Updated the answer with what I believe you're after. Why not post the actual expression, current output and desired output? Combining `Selects` is not the way to do it AFAICS. In your example, your expression is the function `Split-Path` which accepts pipeline input and your dealing with `Get-ChildItem` which has properties you can leverage. In your actual case, you're using the `.Replace` method and I'm assuming an array.

Answer (score 1):

I think the OP is looking for `ForEach-Object` ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object)), which performs an operation against each item in a collection of input objects. It's similar to the `map` or `Select` operation in other languages.

So instead of:

```
ls . `
| select @{ Name="Dir"; Expression = { $_ | Split-Path } } `
| select -ExpandProperty Dir
```

You want:

```
ls . `
| ForEach-Object { $_ | Split-Path }
```

You can also replace `ForEach-Object` with `%`. But it's less readable and less searchable for new PowerShell users:

```
ls . `
| % { $_ | Split-Path }
```